# Spring RestTemplate exchange return 204 and in postman 200

Tags: spring, web-services, postman, spring-rest

I'm turning around since this morning , i've this method that return NO_CONTENT (204) in Java, but when i execute the same URL in postman i got Content (200)

```
String encodedCredentials = getEncodedCredentials(deviceConfigurationInstance);

RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate(url, deviceConfigurationInstance);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Accept", "*/*"); 
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, retType);

return response;
```

I've add the credential in postman also

What i've forgot in Java ?

Note : retType has `Class<T>` as type

Comment: What's under the retType variable. On your code this variable is missing.

Comment: @seti Class<T> the type of retType

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue. I have a rest end point which simply returns `return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);` ..& I do see Status as **204 No Content** in postman. I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: Instead If I return `return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);` where `response != null`, response body is made to be empty / suppressed & Http Response Status remains 204.